# subversive still has reference to old SVN repository server

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Our SVN server has recently moved servers (from serverA to serverB). I did a "relocate" in Eclipse for the repository and moved it to serverB. SVN has been uninstalled from ServerA. When syncing everything is fine, however upon "update" I get the following in the console:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.  
svn: Can't connect to host 'serverA.mysite.com': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

So, somehow there is a reference to the old server stored somewhere, how can I find & change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's somewhere in the `entries` files of your WC (working copy). To find references to `serverA.mysite.com`, utilize the help of grep (in the root of your WC):

```
grep -rni --include "entries" "serverA.mysite.com" .
```

If you're on Windows, you might install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [wingrep](http://www.wingrep.com/) to do the work for you.

Comment: WC? - im on a windows system :(

Comment: This was it. There is a .svn folder in each directory which contains the "entries" file. It was one sub-directory was somehow pointing to a different branch and server

Comment: I see. I did use the search dialog before asking the question, but it didnt find any refs to the old server. Windows is useless.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible solution is that your project tree is using ["externals"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)  feature with explicit urls.

In that case, you'll have to go through your properties and patch them (something like)

```
svn propget svn:externals folder > ext.txt
cat ext.txt | sed -e 's/ServerA/ServerB/' > ext_patch.txt
svn propset svn:externals -F ext_patch.txt folder
```

It should have been done while migrating the depot by your admin however, when the deport was migrated, with a similar regexp on the raw dump. The previous proposition is good for patching live development codeline, but won't patch your existing tags, which became broken.

Note that if you don't know about svn:externals (convenient way to handle external dependencies), my response does not concern you.

**EDIT** : added link to svn doc for externals, added sample code for patching, added exaplanations